# Cluster tags into categories

Tags: clustering

I'm really new - curious about this. Say I have a bunch of objects with a short list of tags, ie ["book", "read", "write"] and ["run", "marathon", "jump"]. I already know that objects in the same "category" will have similar tags. So I'd like to determine how many categories there are and which objects are in them. Any pointers?

Comment: Have a lok at http://p.migdal.pl/tagoverflow/?site=stats&size=32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to your data which might allow me to provide a more detailed example, I might suggest something like k-means clustering or a model-based clustering technique if you are looking for more than just the number of unique tags.

[K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) clustering is a supervised learning technique in which you can

> partition n observations into k clusters in which each observation
>   belongs to the cluster with the nearest mean.

However, this will require you to determine the number of clusters before hand. There are a few techniques that can assist you in this.

Another method is model-based clustering. Many coding environments have built in packages that algorithmically divide your data into the optimum size and number of clusters based on their common characteristics -- the short tags. For instance, this can be done in `R` using the `mclust` package.